# Correspondence betwen aws-sdk-net library version and single component versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

In the past I declared in my ReadMe_OSS file the "aws-sdk-net" 3.7.289.0 source code because I used the AWSSDK.Core 3.7.11.13 lib inside my On premises application.

Now I've upgraded the AWSSDK.Core lib to 3.7.106.35 version.

Which "aws-sdk-net" source code version do I have to download to add it inside my notice file ?

Looked for a crossinfo table but didn't find it